# Django REST Framework - Extending ListAPIView with custom PUT method

Tags: django-rest-framework

I developed APIs using Django REST Framework for an inventory management application.

The endpoint to GET the list of products includes query parameters to filter the list. See below.

**Product List View**:

```
class ProductListAPIView(ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = ProductListSerializer
    queryset = Product.objects.all()
    permission_classes = [DjangoModelPermissionsWithView]
    filter_backends = [SearchFilter, DjangoFilterBackend, OrderingFilter]
    search_fields = [
        'sku',
        'product_name',
        ...
    ]
    filter_class = ProductFilter
    pagination_class = ProductPageNumberPagination
    ordering = ['-id']
    ordering_fields = [
        'id',
        'sku',
        'product_name',
        ...
    ]

    def get_serializer_context(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return {"request": self.request}
```

I have created another view to handle requests in order export the products to PDF, CSV, etc:

```
class ProductExportAPIView(APIView):

    def put(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # We use the seriaziler only to validate request.data
        serializer = ProductExportSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            user_id = request.user.pk
            file_key = request.data.get('file_key')
            file_name = request.data.get('file_name', '')
            extra_args = request.data.get('extra_args', {})
            product_ids = request.data.get('product_ids')
            # NOTE THAT export_file IS A CELERY TASK
            export_file.delay(user_id, file_key, file_name, product_ids, extra_args)
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

The API it's working fine, but it works only if the user selects the products - the `product_ids` field is used to provide the list of products to be exported.

I would like to let the users export ALL the products via `ProductExportAPIView` by providing the query params that I'm using with `ProductListAPIView` rather than providing `product_ids`.
`product_ids` should be an optional field to be used only to export a few products.

How I can enable query parameters filtering on my ProductExportAPIView, there is a way to do this without hardcoding it? Can I extend `ProductListAPIView` with the PUT method to export products?

Comment: What you mean by this, *"I would like to let the users export ALL the products. But they can have the filters enabled"* ??

Comment: @JerinPeterGeorge Let's say that in the database we have 8000 products, but the user has one filter enabled to filter only products that starts with SKU of value "2". The query set will be of 3000 products, but he can see only 50 products per page. Right now the user can select rows of the products' table and then export the selected products. To let the user export all 3000 product I need to pass the same query params to the `ProductExportAPIView` view as I'm doing with ProductListAPIView. But I don't how I can do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to use the same query parameters defined in `ProductListAPIView`, now `ProductExportAPIView` extends `ProductListAPIView`, so it inherits everything I needed:

```
class ProductExportAPIView(ProductListAPIView):
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]
    http_method_names = ['put'] # disable GET method inherited from ProductListAPIView

    def put(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())
        # We use the serializer only to validate request.data
        serializer = ProductExportSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            user_id = request.user.pk
            file_key = request.data.get('file_key')
            file_name = request.data.get('file_name', '')
            extra_args = request.data.get('extra_args', {})
            product_ids = request.data.get('product_ids', [])
            if len(product_ids)==0:
                product_ids = [p.pk for p in queryset]
            export_file.delay(user_id, file_key, file_name, product_ids, extra_args)
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```